# Left join with logic / condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

My title is a bit ambigious but I'll try to clarify below.

I've created a view (A) with a couple of joins. I'm trying to join that view with another view (B). Both views contain a year field, Company ID, Industry ID and a, let's call it, Product code that takes a value of I or U.

View B also contains employee ID, natrually there are multiple employee IDs for every Company ID. Any employee ID could have a Product code that is I, U or both. If it has both there will be 2 identical employee IDs distiguished by the produc code.

Now I want to join view A on Year, Customer ID, Industry ID and Product Code. BUT, since every Customer ID in view B could occure twice (if the underlying employees for that customer have both product code I and U) I only want to join once.

This is the distribution of Customer IDs for Product Codes:

I and NOT U: 165'370

U and NOT I: 45'27

U and I     : 48'920

```
left join [raw].[ViewA] a on a.year=b.year and a.CustomerID=b.CustomerID
and a.IndustryID=b.IndustryID and a.ProductCode ='I'
```

This is the join I'm running with currently, though I'm excluding all records where the CustomerID only have product code U. The reason why I want to only join once per Customer ID/Year/IndustryID is because I'm later on aggregating some other value from View A. Thus, I can't have that value appear twice.

Current result

```
Year CustomerID IndustyID ProductCode Value
2015    A         Z           I         50
2015    A         Z           U         NULL
2015    B         Z           I         40
2016    A         Z           I         20
2016    B         Z           U         NULL
```

What I'd like

```
Year CustomerID IndustyID ProductCode Value
2015    A         Z           I         50
2015    A         Z           U         NULL
2015    B         Z           I         40
2016    A         Z           I         20
2016    B         Z           U         30
```

Comment: Way too much text, way too little data.  I can't see the problem with your data, so it is very hard for me to help you.  Consider editing your question and including sample data which illustrates your problem.

Comment: Please add some sample data from both the views to get this desired results. This will explain more than what you mentioned.

Comment: Hi. Your explanation is not clear. Say what rows appear in the desired result on the basis of what rows appear in the inputs. Give executable example input, DDL, views if necessary & desired output. Also for your current output. Read & act on [mcve]. What do you mean "I want to join view A"? With B? What does "I only want to join once" mean? And you clearly don't *mean* join A to B on columns including product; you mean something *like* that--what *do* you mean? You are not actually writing what you mean or clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, try something as following

[pseudocode]

```
left join ( Select *, rank() over (partition by whatMakesItUnique Order by ProductCode) distinction From tableA ) a
    on your conditions + a.distinction = 1
```

The idea is to assign number 1 either if there are 2 rows for whatMakesItUnique to ProductCode "I" or to "U" when there is only one row and then join on this assigned number

"whatMakesItUnique" are probably columns Year, CustomerID, IndustyID in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what you want with outer apply:

```
outer apply
(select top (1) a.*
 from [raw].[ViewA] a 
 where a.year = b.year and a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID and
       a.IndustryID = b.IndustryID 
 order by (case a.ProductCode when 'I' then 1 when 'U' then 2 else 3 end)
) a
```

This will return one row from `ViewA`, prioritized by the product code.